# Не работает jetty в Eclipse!

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, плагин, jetty

Создал новый Spring MVC и добавил в pom.xml плагин jetty

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
  <configuration>
     <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
     <webApp>
     <contextPath>/abc</contextPath>
     </webApp>
     <httpConnector>
         <port>8080</port>
     </httpConnector>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

При запуске через Eclipse (Run As -> Maven build -> jetty:run ) возникает ошибка

> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and
>   in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\.m2\repository),
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Но когда я запускаю jetty через командную строку, то всё прекрасно работает. 
Может ли, кто-нибудь объяснить как это получилось? и почему с эклипсом постоянно возникает "головная боль"?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно установить плагин, например с помощью команды

```
mvn install
```

Или с помощью Eclipse плагина m2eclipse.